# as3 addEventListener to .copyTo()

Tags: actionscript-3, copy, filestream

Is there a way to add an event listener to the copyTo() function so I 
can run code once the action is complete?

Below is my code and that last line is what I would assume might work, but it doesn't.

```
var sourceDir:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("userSettings.xml");
var resultDir:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("userSettings.xml");
sourceDir.copyTo(resultDir, true);

// Is this possible?                
sourceDir.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileCopied);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [DOCUMENTATION](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#copyTo%28%29) no, but `copyToAsync()` function is dispatching `Event.COMPLETE`.